# Any way to use grey color in Android notification icons? Like Battery and Mobile Data

Tags: android, notifications, icons

As notification icons can only be white, how can the Android Mobile Data and Battery icons use a grey color also?

Are these treated differently?

Comment: You need to developed or generate the icon like that.

Comment: It depends from Android version. In new one, your icons in head bar will be always white.

Comment: Actually, in the "new one", all color information in your image is ignored, except for the alpha channel. Those icons are grey because they're partially transparent.

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

You use the colour white still but set the opacity to 30% as described here.

https://www.google.com/design/spec/style/icons.html#icons-system-icons